# how to remove the default border and toolbar while showing a doc in google docs viewer

Tags: android, google-docs

I am working on an android app which should be able to show pdfs in the app. I am using google docs viewer to show pdf. But the problem I face while using google docs viewer is, it is showing a thick border around the document and also a toolbar which has zoom and other controls on it. Is there any way to remove the border and the tool bar such that all the screen space is occupied by only the pdf doc.

Thanks..

Comment: did u found the answer??.. im facing the same problem

Answer (score 4):

The answer could be found in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26975492/remove-sign-in-button-in-google-docs-webview-in-android) to a similar Stack Overflow issue. If you are using a **Web View** to present the URL to the pdf file, then you should check the following:

- Google Docs viewer **before** your URL: `https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=`
- Embedded parameter: `embedded=true`

So, if the URL to the .pdf file is `http://my.urlto.pdf` then, in order to be previewed using **Google Docs Viewer** via the **Web View** component, you should have the following:

`https://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url=http://my.urlto.pdf`

This way you can preview the file without the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() { 
            @Override 
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                                        String description, String failingUrl) {

            } 

            @Override 
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true; 
            } 

            @Override 
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " + 
                        "document.getElementsByClassName('ndfHFb-c4YZDc-GSQQnc-LgbsSe ndfHFb-c4YZDc-to915-LgbsSe VIpgJd-TzA9Ye-eEGnhe ndfHFb-c4YZDc-LgbsSe')[0].style.display='none'; })()"); 
            } 

            @Override 
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

            } 
        })
```