# Remove sign in button in google docs webview in android

Tags: android, android-webview, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am showing PDF files by using google docs in `WebView` in android.
How to remove or hide "Sign In" button? I have attached screenshot below. Thanks in advance.

```
webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.ex.com/terms.pdf");
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
view.loadUrl(url);
return false;
}
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add the `embedded=true` parameter.

```
webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url=https://orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf");
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }
});
```

**Note:**  This answer was actually proposed by user3777879.  Tested, and working, he should get the credit - Stuart

Comment: I've to open the pdf file saved in google drive using google docs. my drive link is `https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0ecHy3Xov6tT0hINUZ5djRNZkk/view` if It's preceded with google docs format then it looks like `https://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url=https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0ecHy3Xov6tT0hINUZ5djRNZkk/view` which is not a pdf file. How do I open this in google docs in pdf format

Comment: @Prabs  you should probably ask this in its own question.  This answer is specific to this problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39220941/display-the-pdf-filestored-in-google-drive-in-webview-by-using-google-docs/

Comment: This doesn't work in the latest versions of Google Chrome.

Answer (score 8):

## Try this

I have tried to many answers but did not get good answer.
Finally got the solution with adding few code in when loading the pdf into the webview .

```
 final WebView wv_webview= (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.wv_webview);;
    wv_webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv_webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            wv_webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                    "document.querySelector('[role=\"toolbar\"]').remove();})()");
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            wv_webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                    "document.querySelector('[role=\"toolbar\"]').remove();})()");
        }
    });
    String your_pdf_link="https://www.antennahouse.com/XSLsample/pdf/sample-link_1.pdf";
    wv_webview.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + your_pdf_link);
```

**Note:-** It will show only few milliseconds when pdf loads into webview

Output:-[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                    "document.getElementsByClassName('drive-viewer-toolstrip')[0].style.visibility='hidden'; })()");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd self-host your terms document, and I'd host it as `.html` file format rather than `.pdf.`

If you do not have a domain in which to self-host the file, check other file hosting services and see if they offer a public option that won't request login. Potential services that may work for you include Mediafire, Cramitin, Hotfile, Rapidshare, etc. (this is not an ordered or comprehensive list, do your own search).