# How to open documents located in Local Storage in android using WebView?

Tags: android, webview

I have a doc/ppt/xls file located in my sd card. I want to open it without any third party app (i.e within my app itself) using webview. Though I am able to open documents by embedding it in google docs url like -

> http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=[filelinkHere]

But how to open a file located in internal or external storage in webview ?

Also, Suggest me any third party ALL-IN-ONE library for android to view all types of documents. I have tried **ASPOS** but it has few unresolved bugs and **APACHE-POI** is difficult to use.

Comment: Google docs can open the docs hosted on google drive. You cannot open a word file stored on your hard drive into google docs unless you upload it to the drive.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue few days ago .

i found [Android PdfViewer](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer) best to **view PDF files** and [Android PdfMyXml](https://github.com/HendrixString/Android-PdfMyXml) best to **create pdf files** in android.

For working with Word and Excel as a most reliable answer I suggest you to take a look at [OliveDocLibrary](https://code.google.com/p/android-office-demo/downloads/list) .

If your documents are in cloud so there is an alternative way to display docx,pptx,pdf and such formats with a [combination of Webview and googleDoc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27908545/4799599).

You might find other possible solutions in server-side machines or maybe a creative way!

Hope it help

Comment: OliveDocLibrary . - [link](https://code.google.com/p/android-office-demo/downloads/list) this link is not working. Could you please provide me any other alternate link or suggestions ?

Comment: Olive library gone now for a reason! I suggest you to try a different way now. Please share with us if you find any thing useful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate some library project to your project with which you can open the pdf file inside your app.

Reference :
https://github.com/tekinarslan/AndroidPdfViewer
https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview

Comment: Thanks Nitesh. But I want a library or a way that could open